# Looping through an Excel workbook from Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to get the last used work request number to fill in the next number in the sequence. I have included the Excel object library. I am getting a type mismatch error on the beginning of the second for loop but when I run the same code within Excel it works as desired. The code snippet is provided below:

```
Sub GetDRNum()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim xl as Excel.Application, Wb As Excel.Workbook, I As integer
    Dim ReqNum As String, lr As long, c As Range, lastReqNum As Long,
    nextReqNum As String, rngStr As String

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set Wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("K:\Desktop\IT Projects\IT Help Request\LTO-IT DR Log(revised).xlsm")

    For i = 1 To Wb.Sheets.Count
        With Wb.Sheets(i)
            If .Name = "Validation" Then
               'skip validation worksheet
                GoTo myNext
            ElseIf .Name = "Submitted" Then
                rngStr = "B6:B"
            ElseIf .Name = "Completed Requests" Then
                rngStr = "B4:B"
            End If
            lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each c in WB.Sheets(i).Range(rngStr & lr)
                If IsEmpty(c) Then
                    Exit For
                ElseIf CLng(Right(Trim(c), 4)) > lastReqNum Then
                    lastReqNum = CLng(Right(Trim(c), 4))
                End If
            Next c
        End With
myNext:
    Next i
```

Comment: Is it a typo to the post where `For i= To`? Try `For i=1 To`. Anyway, `c As Range` is within Word. You may need `c As Excel.Range`

Comment: yes it was a typo and was to be I = 1. Ill try changing it to Excel.range when  get to work tomorrow thank you.

Comment: Changing the range to Excel.Range did it thank you. How do i mark this as answered and give Patrick credit?

Comment: Patrick needs to copy the content of his Comment to an "Answer". Address a comment to him using @PatricK at the beginning of it and he should see it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [Word has a Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846324(v=office.14).aspx) as well (think of it a range of text).

You will need to define your Excel range like you define the Excel App.

```
Dim c As Excel.Range
```

Please note that this Word macro can only work if the Word application of the logged in user has been adding the Excel Object reference manually.

i.e. If you take this to another computer it won't work by default. So I suggest you to use Late Binding if you want portability - make them all Excel related to `As Object`.